# Using Through at lowest

Tags: syntax

This works

```
Through[{#*2 &, #*8 &}[a]]

{2 a, 8 a}
```

But if I want to generalize to a 2 dimensional array of functions like this

```
Through[{{#*2 &, #*8 &}, {#*3 &, #*5 &}}[a]]
```

It doesn't work.  I've tried to add a third argument to `Through`  such as `1` or `2` or `{1,1}` and this doesn't help.  To be clear, I know how to work around this, but I just don't understand why it isn't easy to generalize `through` to a general array of functions.

Comment: Working around it: `Through[#[a]] & /@ {{#*2 &, #*8 &}, {#*3 &, #*5 &}}`

Comment: `{{#*2, #*8}, {#*3, #*5}} &[a]` ? In other words, apply one function with the required structure?

Comment: Thank for the work arounds.    That is currently what I have in my code.  However, I'm just frustrated that Through doesn't have an obvious extension to arrays greater than one dimension.

Comment: Through doesn't assume that the head of the head is List. And it certainly doesn't assume that the head is a full matrix. So, there would need to be some way to recursively find the same head-head symbol at all levels of the head structure and then figure out how it's supposed to be applied. That seems very complicated and not as semantically clear as the current Through definition. Probably better to go with one of the Map- or Apply-related functions.

Comment: @lericr  Thanks for explaining why Through works the way it does and why it doesn't have an obvious generalization.  This could be answer to the question if you elaborate a bit more and explain in more detail your answer.

Comment: FWIW I think that the right method for this problem was given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284571/using-through-at-lowest#comment708629_284571) - I think that is not a workaround for a limitation in `Through` but just the correct method to solve this problem (I never use `Through` for anything).  But I don't understand closing this question - how is it opinion based?

Comment: It is unfortunate this question is closed because several creative approaches to the problem appeared over the last few hours.

Answer (score 3):

I propose :

```
Map[#[a] &, {{#*2 &, #*8 &}, {#*3 &, #*5 &}}, {2}]
```

> {{2 a, 8 a}, {3 a, 5 a}}

Though I have never used it.

Comment: My objection to this workout around is that it isn't readable, in the sense that I  can't just look at it and red it like an english sentence.

Answer (score 3):

```
Through/@Through[{{#*2 &, #*8 &}, {#*3 &, #*5 &}}[a]]

(*{{2*a, 8*a}, {3*a, 5*a}} *)
```

**(2)**

```
Through[{{f, g},{x,y}}[a]]
(* {{f, g}[a], {x, y}[a]} *)
```

and:

```
Through/@Through[{{f, g},{x,y}}[a]]

(* {{f[a], g[a]}, {x[a], y[a]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I learn this from someone.

```
Clear[operator];
operator[head_] := head[a];
SetAttributes[operator, Listable];
operator[{{#*2 &, #*8 &}, {#*3 &, #*5 &}, {# &, # &, # &}, # &}]
```

> `{{2 a, 8 a}, {3 a, 5 a}, {a, a, a}, a}`.